# maximum size for an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I tried zeros(1500*64) but it says "Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded."
But [C,MAXSIZE] = COMPUTER returns MAXSIZE = 2.1475e+009
So why isn't it working? Also, after trying to issue this aommand on the Matlab command line a few times, I tried everything from zeroes(500*64) to zeros(1500*64) to find the maximum allowed, and sometimes it returned "Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded." for 500*64 and sometimes returned "Out of memory." error. What could be the reason for that? This is what the memory command returns:

> Maximum possible array:             486 MB (5.094e+008 bytes) * Memory
>   available for all arrays:   1436 MB (1.506e+009 bytes) ** Memory used
>   by MATLAB:              353 MB (3.697e+008 bytes) Physical Memory
>   (RAM):             3070 MB (3.219e+009 bytes)
>
> - Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
>     ** Limited by virtual address space available.

Output of [u,s] = memory

[u, s] = memory

u =

> ```
> MaxPossibleArrayBytes: 509411328
> MemAvailableAllArrays: 1.5057e+009
>         MemUsedMATLAB: 369819648
> ```
>
> s =
>
> ```
> VirtualAddressSpace: [1x1 struct]
>        SystemMemory: [1x1 struct]
>      PhysicalMemory: [1x1 struct]
> ```

How do I calculate my allowed maximum size from this information, both in terms of nuber of elements and total bytes occupied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
 x = zeros(1500*64);
```

attempts to create a square matrix of double precision zeros, 96000 elements per side, requiring 73 gigabytes.

I suspect you want to use

```
x = zeros(1500,64);
```

which creates a 1500-by-64 array of double precision zeros, requiring 0.8 megabytes of memory.

Comment: That's undoubtedly the mistake user13267 made.  Not really the question asked, but that isn't your fault.  +1

Comment: sorry about that; my mistake; Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When I google for that error message, first hit is a descriptive help page from MathWorks, the developer of MatLab:

- [Why do I get the error 'Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.' ?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA99T5/index.html)

According to that, you should use the `computer` command, not `memory`, to learn the maximum matrix size supported by your edition of MatLab.

For the "Out of Memory" error, take the "Maximum possible array: 486 MB (5.094e+008 bytes)" reported by `memory`, and divide by the size of an array element (8 bytes for double-precision real values, which is what MatLab uses by default).  The reason it's so low is due to address space fragmentation, which is what the `memory` command is telling you when it talks about "Limited by contiguous address space".